# Offline maps unavailable during update

Tags: android, here-api

We're using the latest version of here android sdk and we use MapLoader to download and update the offline maps packages.

Recently we noticed that on a device with slow internet bandwith, the map was not rendering on the screen during the update of the map package (black screen in MapFragment, every other part of the app worked fine). So I suspect that the offline maps are unavailable during the map update.

Are they unavailable as I suspect ? If it is, will this change in future version ? What can I do to continue offline maps during updates ? If it is not, why am I not seeing the maps during the update, the map package is installed as the update has been detected by MapLoader.Listener#onCheckForUpdateComplete ?

Thank you

Comment: This issue is not reproducible. We tried it on emulator with different network speed option as well on real devices within the latest SDK release. Can you please check once again? If the issue is still shown on your side please provide us some sample code and the exact steps you did.

Comment: I can't simulate map package upgrades as I can't revert to an old package as I don't see any method in the here sdk that allow the download/installation of a specific version (only the latest is available). If you want me to try again, please tell me how I can force a map package upgrade.

Comment: @Teriblus, there is no way to downgrade map data version.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not reproducible as the HERE mobile SDK has been updated with new features and bug fixes. Please checkout the new APIs and the many examples that we provide:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/system-requirements.html

https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples